# Filter entities that are in list B but not in A

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a DB table called `Autoline_PL_00_trans`, which represents received credit notes. The credit notes have to be manually entered to our dealer management system and after that, marked as "booked" in my app. In a section of the app, I'd like to present, from the entire list of credit notes, those who have not yet been marked as "booked". If they were marked as booked, I just write them back to the `FundsBooked` table. I cannot store any data to the `Autoline_PL_00_trans` table since that's the DB of our dealer management system which I have read-only access. Both tables come from two different databases, which makes using a single dbcontext impossible. That is the structure of the attributes I have available:

```
public class Autoline_PL_00_trans
{
    public string CreditNoteNumber {get; set;}
    public decimal Amount {get; set;}
    public DateTime ReceivedDate {get; set;}
}

public class FundsBooked
{
    public string CreditNoteNumber {get; set;}
    public bool IsBooked {get; set;}
}
```

allFunds = alContext.Autoline_PL_00_trans.ToList();
fundsBooked = gwContext.FundsBooked.ToList();

What I now need are all the Fundings, that are not yet booked, so the entities that are in allFundings but not in fundsBooked, based on the CreditNoteNumber as key. In my test data I have one FundsBooked that is also represented in Autoline_PL_00_trans. This is what I tried to come up with but I think that does not work

**Native linq/efcore approach:**

```
var notBooked allFunds.Select(x => x.CreditNoteNumber ).Except(fundsBooked.Select(y => y.CreditNoteNumber )).ToList();
```

**--> empty result set**

**Raw SQL approach:**

The raw sql statement that works in my MS SQL workbench would be:

```
SELECT 
      [SupplierReference]          
  FROM [Autoline_Basis].[dbo].[Autoline_PL_00_trans] t1
  Where NOT EXISTS (
        select [SupplierReference] 
        from [LUX_WEB_Goodwill].[dbo].[FundsBooked] t2
        Where t1.SupplierReference = t2.SupplierReference       
)
```

When I try to translate that to c#, it looks like this:

```
 var notBooked = gwContext.FundsBooked.FromSqlRaw("SELECT [SupplierReference] FROM [Autoline_Basis].[dbo].[Autoline_PL_00_trans] t1 " +
                "Where NOT EXISTS (select [SupplierReference] from [LUX_WEB_Goodwill].[dbo].[FundsBooked] t2" +
                "Where t1.SupplierReference = t2.SupplierReference)")
                .ToList();
```

But I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 't1'.'

Edit: alright folks, I sorted out my problems and finally found the working solution:

```
 var notBooked = alContext.AutolinePl00Trans.FromSqlRaw("SELECT [SupplierReference], [DocumentDate], [DocumentBaseTotal] FROM [Autoline_Basis].[dbo].[Autoline_PL_00_trans] t1 " +
                "Where NOT EXISTS (select [SupplierReference] from [LUX_WEB_Goodwill].[dbo].[FundsBooked] t2 " +
                "Where t1.SupplierReference = t2.SupplierReference)  AND t1.SupplierReference LIKE '306%N%'").Select(x => new { x.SupplierReference, x.DocumentDate, x.DocumentBaseTotal})
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Loading an entire table in memory is a bug unless you want to load a *small* lookup table. Without indexes, you have to loop over all data to find matches. Fix your EF query so it runs in the database, or use SQL directly. It's *not* hard to write a query that retrieves records with no match on another table. It's either a `LEFT JOIN` on a common key or a `NOT EXISTS`. You could use `EXCEPT` but unless the query contained only indexed columns, the query would be slow.

Comment: I just made a major edit on my questions since the data comes from two different tables (which wasn't an issue following my original strategy). But I think when using RawSql it becomes a problem.

Comment: As the duplicate shows, it's not a problem. You forgot to add spaces between lines. The duplicate shows both the SQL and the EF way of finding differences. In LINQ you need to add `.Where(f=> !db.FundsBooked.Any(fb => fb.CreditNoteNumber == f.CreditNoteNumber))`

Comment: After some more hurdles I finally managed to get it done using Raw SQL. Thanks giving some direction!